# Where can I find the iptables rules in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, iptables, rules

I just installed CentOS 7 and I need to modify some existing iptables rules, but I cannot find the file where these rules are. Can you please help me find where are the default rules that are loaded once the system boots?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the rules live but the firewall seems to be controlled by firewalld by default.

See http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD for some information (and of course the man pages).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I didn't find what I needed, but it will have to do :)

Answer (score 0):

They are found under /etc/sysconfig/iptables

You can also view them using:

iptables -L or

iptables -S